# using hash(#) in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone clarify why I have to use a # here?

```
#If Win64 Then
    do something
#Else
    do something else
#End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Prefixing with a # means you are specifying compiler directives and compiling different sets of code depending on values that have been predefined e.g Win64 or which you have defined yourself by adding values to Tools.PropertiesGeneral.Conditional Compilation Arguments.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/directives